# Physical meaning of results in Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, physics, complex-integration

It appears to me that many results in complex analysis "kind of" have meaning in physics, but I struggle to find a clear explanation.

1. Cauchy's integration theorem. It's quite common in physics to have contour integrals equal to zero in a potential. However, those potentials are all real-valued function, and I struggle to find a "complex-valued" example.
2. Liouville's theorem, or Picardy's little theorem. I remember someone telling me about their meaning in physics, but I cannot remember it now. Can anyone give me a clue?

I would really appreaciate physical interpretation of other theorems as well.

Are there any good books that includes such interpretation in physics?

Comment: You can find complex potential in 2D fluid mechanics, because the velocity is curl-free, i.e. $v=\nabla \Phi$ and it's divergence-free as well, i.e. $v=\nabla \times [0,0,\Psi]$. The same applies for the 2D electrostatics: If the charge density is zero, and the magnetic field is constant in time, then we have that $\nabla E = 0$ and $\nabla \times E = 0$.

Comment: @Botond I have thought about that as well, but my attempt here (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/475906/can-i-write-a-2-dimensional-electric-field-as-an-analytic-function-on-the-comple) is futile. Please provid an aswer if you know it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't usually. Take the "simplest" example, a point charge. Then we have that $E=\frac{r}{|r|^3}$ (leaving the constants out). If we identify the vector $r=[x,y]$ with $z=x+iy$, then we have that $E_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^3}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sqrt{z \bar{z}}^3}}$, $E_y$ is similar, so we can write $E(z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{z \bar{z}}^3}$, which is not analytic, I think.

Comment: I would go for Schrodinger's equation. The wavefunction can be complex. The measurable quantities are real (probabilities), since they involve the absolute value squared.

Comment: @Andrei The wave equation is only complex valued, and here I am focusing on functions that have complex input.